# Use php to update mysql custom rank field

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I would like to find a way to update a Custom Rank field in MySQL so that it will renumber all other items accordingly.

Sample Data:

```
ID     Name    Ranking
12     Sara    1
13     Mike    2
14     John    3
15     Susie   4
16     Melissa 5
17     Jane    6
```

If, via PHP, I update `'Jane'` to ranking position `2`, I would like everybody from `'Mike'` down to `'Melissa'` to be moved to position `3` to `6`.

`Set Ranking=2 where ID=17`, and find a way to loop through the rest to increase their ranking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
if($curSort > $setSort){
    // "UPDATE table SET Ranking = (Ranking + 1) WHERE Ranking >= $setSort AND Ranking < $curSort"
} elseif($curSort < $setSort){
    // "UPDATE table SET Ranking = (Ranking - 1) WHERE Ranking > $curSort AND Ranking <= $setSort"
}
///update $curSort to $setSort
```

Where $curSort = 6; and $setSort = 2;

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using something like the following.

```
SET @val = 0;

UPDATE table_name SET Ranking = (@val:=@val+1) ORDER BY column_name;
```

Here you would order by the column that you were sorting by, for example, if you had a column which contained total score. and you wanted to order by score descending, this would update the ranking accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Create a PHP array with id as key and ranking as value, ordered by ranking DESC.

```
$ranking = array(12 => 1, 13 => 2, 14 => 3, 15 => 4, 16 => 5, 17 => 6); //array described above

$new_rank_id_user = 17; //id of the user you want to change the rank
$new_rank_user = 2; //new rank of this user 

foreach ($ranking as $id_user => $rank_user) { //loop over all users
    if ($rank_user >= $new_rank_user) { //if the current user needs to go down
        $ranking[$id_user] = $rank_user + 1; 
    }
}

$ranking[17] = 2; //finally place this user at the good place
```

And here you go with an array you can loop over again to get id and new rank of each one.

You can also sort this array to get them ordered by rank (if needed) with `asort($ranking)` or by id with `ksort($ranking)`